# Size of app update in Play Store

Tags: android, google-play

My app is on Google Play for a week. Original apk size was about 40MB. Few days later I updated the app and now it's 46MB. And here problem begins: users, to update the app, need to download 46MB, not something around 6MB. 
I think it isn't okay, as other apps in PlayStore only download needed data and not whole new apk. So: am I doing something wrong or should I turn on something in Play Dev Console?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Answer (score 1):

Play Store tries to download deltas of your changes when updating an app, not the whole APK. See [this article](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/07/improvements-for-smaller-app-downloads.html) for some of these optimization, including some tips.

Comment: I know that Google Play reduces apk update sizes, but in my it doesn't work.

Comment: Where did you got this figures from? Play Store console? Play Store app in the phone? You have to trust the later, and only in the case of upgrades, of course. Also, notice that the process is automatic, and I don't think there's an option in the Play Store console to disable it.

Comment: I tested it on my own phone. To update, I had to download full size apk.